# $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln(bx+1)}{\ln(ax^2 + 3)}$ =

Tags: limits

A question reads: If $a$ and $b$ are positive constants, then

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln(bx+1)}{\ln(ax^2 + 3)} =$$

I would think the answer is $0$ since the bottom grows faster than the top. However, answer sheet says that $1/2$ is the answer. How so?

Comment: can you use L'Hospital?

Comment: You can, but that also seems to lead to 0: Taking the derivative of the top and bottom:  

$ frac{\frac {b}{bx+1}}{\frac{2a}{ax^2+3}) $

Comment: i think the Limit is not zero

Comment: Using l'hopital we can see the limes is 0, assuming a,b > 0 otherwise this wouldn't make sense, since ln(x) is not defined for x < 0

Comment: ln(x)/ln(x^2)  = 1/2.   But ln(ax+1) approaches ln(x) and ln(ax^2+3) approaches ln(x^2) so the quotient approaches 1/2.

Answer (score 1):

we use L'Hosptal and we have $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{b(ax^2+3)}{(bx+1)2ax}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{ab+\frac{3}{x^2}}{2ab+\frac{2a}{x}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Logarithm decreases the rate of change of number tremendously ; from powers to just multiplication. So you cannot just comment that denominator is far more bigger than numerator.For instance, $\log x^3$ is just three times larger than $\log x$. So it's better to use     rules of limit to solve.
As $x \rightarrow \infty$

$$ \log (bx+1) \sim \log {bx} =    \log x+\log b
\sim \log x$$

Similarly ; 
$$ \log (ax^2+3) \sim \log (ax^2) =    \Big (\log x^2+\log a \Big )
\sim  \log x^2$$

Therefore :

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac {\log(bx+1)}{\log(ax^2+3)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac {\log(x)}{\log(x^2)}=\frac12$$

Comment: Are you sure $\log x+\log b\to\log x$ as $x\to\infty$? I think you want something along the lines of $\log x+\log b\sim\log x$ (and similarly for the next line).

Comment: @A. Howells, what makes difference in both the notations, here.

Comment: The first, (as I have always seen it defined) would mean that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $x>N$, $|(\log x-\log b)-(\log x)|<\varepsilon$. The second would mean that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x-\log b}{\log x}=1$.

Comment: @A.Howells Understood, I was wrong.My solution interpreted $\log b \rightarrow 0$ .(As I have understood)